# Polygon center which always lies inside the polygon (with no hole)

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, polygons

Is there is any type of centre (of polygon) which always lies inside the polygon (with no hole)?

Note: Here our polygon may be any type of polygon (convex or concave) but `not self intersecting`.

Comment: You are unlikely to find anything useful, considering that the polygon may be something like a thin spiraling shape. An artificial definition of some sort can be given, as long as one doesn't expect the "center" to have any other properties except being contained within.

Comment: @Woodface Thanks for your attention. I understand your point. Here we are considering polygons which are not self intersecting. I added it in my question. Do you think in this case also getting a reasonable center (inside polygon) is very unlikely?

Comment: The shape I had in mind is non-self-intersecting: something like [shaded region here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/PolygonalSpiralSolid_800.gif)

Comment: @Woodface...Ok I got your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polygon doesn't have to have a hole to be an awkward shape. Snaky branching forms, including spirals, will be awkward, and it's easy to have a polygon that has a large "central" void:

[image]

... and that one's simple compared to something more like a tree.

[image]

It strikes me that perhaps you could define a "minimum-path" centre, that point with the shortest maximum path length to any point in the the polygon given a path that is entirely inside the polygon.

[Here's an interesting paper](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~moret/cs506/guibas-hershberger.pdf) on efficiently finding paths in these kind of polygons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could please explain a little bit, how it can be compared to a tree.

Comment: Added another image that is more branchy.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. But here we have some issues to solve: How to select the given `path` in side the polygon? Another issue is that it contains infinite number points on it, so may be we need to select some equi-spaced points from the path.

Comment: We have specified that there are no holes in the polygon, so there should be no ambiguity about the shortest path between two points. Thread a string inside the polygon from point to point and pull tight. It will essentially be a set of straight line segments taking the "inside curve" on each change of direction. The trick with that definition - and I don't know that it does lead to a unique point always, although I'd think it usually does - is finding the maximally separated points, and taking the mid-point of that path.

Comment: Your reference is very interesting. Thank you.